# Alfresco share - Tags not displayed in Tag Management

Tags: alfresco-share

When creating a folder rule with rule criteria 'Has tag', the Select Tag panel doesn't display all tags [image: Select Tag panel]

I have tried creating a tag by adding a tag in the file properties but it's still not showing [image: Add tag]

I checked the tag management, it's not showing there either!

I'm using activiti for managing workflows, and I tried adding tags like it shows in the code below:

```
    <userTask id="reviewTask" name="Review Task"
        activiti:formKey="wfa:activitiReviewTaskk">
       <extensionElements>
           <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
              <activiti:field name="script">
                 <activiti:string>
                    if (typeof bpm_workflowDueDate != 'undefined') task.dueDate = bpm_workflowDueDate
                    if (typeof bpm_workflowPriority != 'undefined') task.priority = bpm_workflowPriority;
                 </activiti:string>
              </activiti:field>
           </activiti:taskListener>
           <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
              <activiti:field name="script">
                 <activiti:string>
                    execution.setVariable('wfa_reviewOutcome', task.getVariable('wfa_reviewOutcome'));
                    if (task.getVariable('wfa_reviewOutcome') == 'Approve')
                    {

                       bpm_package.children[0].addTag("Approved");


                    }
                    else
                    {
                            if (task.getVariable('wfa_reviewOutcome') == 'Reject')
                            {
                                bpm_package.children[0].addTag("Rejected");
                            }
                    }
                 </activiti:string>
              </activiti:field>
              <activiti:field name="runAs">  
                 <activiti:string>admin</activiti:string>  
              </activiti:field> 
           </activiti:taskListener>
       </extensionElements>
        <humanPerformer>
            <resourceAssignmentExpression>
                <formalExpression>${bpm_assignee.properties.userName}</formalExpression>
            </resourceAssignmentExpression>
        </humanPerformer>
    </userTask>
```

The tags are added but still not showing in the tags management!

Comment: Have you tested this as admin user ? May be permission issue ? Any information on alfresco.log ?

Comment: @MuralidharanDeenathayalan I tested this with admin user and i checked alfresco log when creating a new tag nothing suspicious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by performing a reindex of SOLR by following the steps in this link, http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/solr-reindex.html :

- Delete the content of the directories
  ..\alf_data\solr4\index\workspace\SpacesStore\ and
  ..\alf_data\solr4\index\archive\SpacesStore\
- Delete all the files in ..\alf_data\solr4\model